# Bash change user info (like usermod) but without root privileges

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a small GUI program for a user to edit their own account.
You cannot run usermod as a regular user, I am looking for that kind of functionality.

Changing a users fullname is the most important. Any other help or info would be great as well.

Comment: Changing user information requires access to `/etc/passwd`, which is owned by root and not writeable by others. No dice. Being root or having appropriate `sudo` permissions is the only way (and I seriously doubt the latter will be granted to some self-written GUI app by any security-aware admin).

Comment: i'm afraid this will be everyone's answer. only function a user may perform themselves is changing password.

Comment: It's quite logical if you think about it. Only the admin (root) decides who may log in, usually after asserting their identity. So allowing people to change how they appear on the system - i.e. "disguising" themselves - would be defeating the purpose of access control. The way to change your fullname is to talk to your system administrator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `chfn` and `chsh` utilities should be available on the system, and should do what you want - they will change the gecos field (real name and so on) and login shell, respectively, based on configurable rules, without needing to write code that runs with root privileges yourself (that's not *hard*, it's just that the cost of errors is very, very high).

From the chfn man page:

```
   The chfn command changes user fullname, office room number,
   office phone number, and home phone number information for a
   user's account.
```

From the chsh man page:

```
   The chsh command changes the user login shell. This determines the name of the
   user's initial login command. A normal user may only change the login shell
   for her own account; the superuser may change the login shell for any account.
```

Comment: that is what i was looking for, though on my system it says permission denied for changing full name. must be a debian defaulted behavior for security. if anyone can give a fix for it that would be helpful.

Comment: From `man chfn`: "The following configuration variables in /etc/login.defs change the behavior of this tool: CHFN_RESTRICT (string) This parameter specifies which values [...] may be changed by regular users [...] It can be any combination of letters f, r, w, h, for Full name, Room number, Work phone, and Home phone, respectively."

Comment: yes, i found that as well, default did not allow full name, i simply added it. now i can work on the gui

Answer (score 0):

The best (and worst) answer is: you write setuid() code.

Based on your question, you probably should not do this kind of code. In linux, you cannot execute a bash script in setuid mode, if memory serves, you have to write and compile a C/C++ program, then have the root user set the setuid permissions bit on the compiled code.  At any rate setuid bash scripts are a bad idea security wise.

This whole area is such a problem security-wise, that there are loads of sites offering help.

[Safe setuid programs](http://nob.cs.ucdavis.edu/bishop/secprog/)

[GNU example C code](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html)